# update asp.net update panel without postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the following, if you click either of the .net buttons the update panel refreshes. but no matter what I do I cant seem to get the panel to refresh using an onclick event. if you click the "html button" the whole page refreshes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var UpdatePanel1 = '<%=UpdatePanel1.ClientID%>';
    function fireButton() {
        //__doPostBack(UpdatePanel1, '');
        $('#<%=Button2.ClientID%>').submit();
    }
</script>

   <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button3" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            <%=DateTime.Now.ToString() %>
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" 
                            Text="Refresh Panel" 
                            runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <p><%=DateTime.Now.ToString() %></p>
    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="other refresh button" />
    <button onclick="fireButton()">html button</button>
```

can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: You seem to be trying to trigger the update from inside the content template. Wierd

Comment: Can you expand a bit, I've also tried firing "Button3" but its the same

Comment: First frame your question properly, answering your question may get me downvotes.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly telling the event to use javascript?

onclick="javascript:fireButton(this);"

Comment: Yes the javascript was firing the event click event on the button

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript doesn't look right. Try this:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().beginAsyncPostBack(new Array('updatePanelId'));
```

Comment: No that just does exactly the same. When I fire the .click or .submit event on any of the asp.net buttons it's like it looses it's trigger